# refreshing guide with radiobutton and slider

Tags: matlab, slider, radio-button, matlab-guide

I have a question that include radiobuttons and slider. My aim is this: when the value of the slider is changed, the code in the radiobutton selected in the moment must be rerun to refresh the effect.

te max, min and step of the slider is defined in the opening function and the current value is  defined to `handles.value`.

here's my slider code.

```
function slider1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to slider1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

handles.svalue = get(handles.slider1, 'Value');

guidata(hObject, handles)
```

here's my radiobutton group selection change code.

```
function uipanel3_SelectionChangeFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to the selected object in uipanel3 
% eventdata  structure with the following fields (see UIBUTTONGROUP)
%   EventName: string 'SelectionChanged' (read only)
%   OldValue: handle of the previously selected object or empty if none was selected
%   NewValue: handle of the currently selected object
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
switch get(eventdata.NewValue,'Tag') % Get Tag of selected object.
    case 'hte'
        h_te = zeros(handles.rows, handles.colums);

        for m = handles.row_0:handles.rows
            gauss = fspecial('gaussian',[1 round(1+handles.svalue*(m-handles.row_0+1))], (0.3*round(1+handles.svalue*(m-handles.row_0+1))));
            h_te(m,:,1) = filter2(gauss, handles.img_d(m,:,1));
            h_te(m,:,2) = filter2(gauss, handles.img_d(m,:,2));
            h_te(m,:,3) = filter2(gauss, handles.img_d(m,:,3));
            h_te(handles.rows-m+1,:,1) = filter2(gauss, handles.img_d(handles.rows-m+1,:,1));
            h_te(handles.rows-m+1,:,2) = filter2(gauss, handles.img_d(handles.rows-m+1,:,2));
            h_te(handles.rows-m+1,:,3) = filter2(gauss, handles.img_d(handles.rows-m+1,:,3));
        end

        axes(handles.axes2);
        imshow(h_te);

    case 'hc'
        h_c = zeros(handles.rows, handles.colums);

        for m = handles.row_0:handles.rows
            gauss = fspecial('gaussian',[1 round(1+handles.svalue*(m-handles.row_0+1))], (0.3*round(1+handles.svalue*(m-handles.row_0+1))));
            h_c(m-handles.row_0+1,:,1) = filter2(gauss, handles.img_d(m-handles.row_0+1,:,1));
            h_c(m-handles.row_0+1,:,2) = filter2(gauss, handles.img_d(m-handles.row_0+1,:,2));
            h_c(m-handles.row_0+1,:,3) = filter2(gauss, handles.img_d(m-handles.row_0+1,:,3));
            h_c(handles.rows-m+handles.row_0,:,1) = filter2(gauss, handles.img_d(handles.rows-m+handles.row_0,:,1));
            h_c(handles.rows-m+handles.row_0,:,2) = filter2(gauss, handles.img_d(handles.rows-m+handles.row_0,:,2));
            h_c(handles.rows-m+handles.row_0,:,3) = filter2(gauss, handles.img_d(handles.rows-m+handles.row_0,:,3));
        end

        axes(handles.axes2);
        imshow(h_c);

    case 'vlr'
        v_lr = zeros(handles.rows, handles.colums);

        for m = handles.colum_0:handles.colums
            gauss = fspecial('gaussian',[round(1+handles.svalue*(m-handles.colum_0+1)) 1], (0.3*round(1+handles.svalue*(m-handles.colum_0+1))));
            v_lr(:,m,1) = filter2(gauss, handles.img_d(:,m,1));
            v_lr(:,m,2) = filter2(gauss, handles.img_d(:,m,2));
            v_lr(:,m,3) = filter2(gauss, handles.img_d(:,m,3));
            v_lr(:,handles.colums-m+1,1) = filter2(gauss, handles.img_d(:,handles.colums-m+1,1));
            v_lr(:,handles.colums-m+1,2) = filter2(gauss, handles.img_d(:,handles.colums-m+1,2));
            v_lr(:,handles.colums-m+1,3) = filter2(gauss, handles.img_d(:,handles.colums-m+1,3));
        end

        axes(handles.axes2);
        imshow(v_lr);

    case 'vc'
        v_c = zeros(handles.rows, handles.colums);

        for m = handles.colum_0:handles.colums
            gauss = fspecial('gaussian',[round(1+handles.svalue*(m-handles.colum_0+1)) 1], (0.3*round(1+handles.svalue*(m-handles.colum_0+1))));
            v_c(:,m-handles.colum_0+1,1) = filter2(gauss, handles.img_d(:,m-handles.colum_0+1,1));
            v_c(:,m-handles.colum_0+1,2) = filter2(gauss, handles.img_d(:,m-handles.colum_0+1,2));
            v_c(:,m-handles.colum_0+1,3) = filter2(gauss, handles.img_d(:,m-handles.colum_0+1,3));
            v_c(:,handles.colums-m+handles.colum_0,1) = filter2(gauss, handles.img_d(:,handles.colums-m+handles.colum_0,1));
            v_c(:,handles.colums-m+handles.colum_0,2) = filter2(gauss, handles.img_d(:,handles.colums-m+handles.colum_0,2));
            v_c(:,handles.colums-m+handles.colum_0,3) = filter2(gauss, handles.img_d(:,handles.colums-m+handles.colum_0,3));
        end

        axes(handles.axes2);
        imshow(v_c);

end
guidata(hObject, handles)
```

I thought calling the uipanel3 function inside the slider one would work but it does not. here's what I thought would work.

```
function slider1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to slider1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

handles.svalue = get(handles.slider1, 'Value');

uipanel3_SelectionChangeFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles);

guidata(hObject, handles)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work because hObject and eventdata are for the slider, not for the buttongroup, so eventdata does not contain fields you are looking for. You can manually generate eventdata with required fields, although it is a bit of a hack and Oldvalue is not really what it should be...

Try

```
eventdata_new.EventName = 'SelectionChanged';
eventdata_new.OldValue = get(handles.uipanel3,'SelectedObject');
eventdata_new.NewValue = get(handles.uipanel3,'SelectedObject');

uipanel3_SelectionChangeFcn(handles.uipanel3, eventdata_new, handles);
```

instead of

```
uipanel3_SelectionChangeFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles);
```